# Is the concept of "The Seamstress" found in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, upanishads

The Pali suttas of Buddhism only mention the Four Vedas as sacred Brahmin texts; giving the impression of both predating the Upanishad period.

In the Pali suttas of Buddhism, there is [an account](https://suttacentral.net/snp5.1/en/anandajoti) of a Brahmin guru named Bāvari (in the locality of [Assaka, near to Mūḷaka](https://suttacentral.net/define/a%E1%B8%B7aka), close to the bank of the Godhāvarī River) who sends out his disciples to speak to the Buddha Gotama. One of the Brahmin Bāvari's disciples named [Tissa Metteyya](https://suttacentral.net/snp5.3/en/anandajoti) is said to have asked Buddha Gotama the following question (per the Pali text):

> Kassa no santi iñjitā;Ko ubhantamabhiññāya, Majjhe mantā na lippati;
> Kaṃ brūsi mahāpurisoti, Ko idha **sibbini**maccagā
>
> Who is the wise man, who has known both ends, and is undefiled in the
> middle? Who do you say is a Great Man? Who has gone beyond **the
> seamstress** (sibbini) here?”

In the Vedas or, otherwise, Upanishads, is there any account of these persons (Brahmin Bāvari; Tissa Metteyya; etc) and, in particular, the notion/concept of "The Seamstress"?